# Cygwin install does not have shared libraries, or how should I activate the shared libraries?

Tags: cygwin, shared

I'm new to Cygwin - so hopefully, someone can point me in the right direction. I would like to be able to choose to use the shared libraries to compile my code. However, so far, it seems that it always uses the static library, and I don't know where exactly I did wrong.

I installed Cygwin on my Windows 10 computer. Created a file: `test.c`, which contains:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    const char msg[] = "Hello, world.";

    int main(void){
        puts (msg);
        return 0;
    }
```

I then compiled it with:
`$ gcc -Wall -c test.c -o test.o`

Then I checked the symbols using:
`$ nm test.o`

It gives me what I expected:

```
                 U __main
0000000000000000 T main
0000000000000000 R msg
                 U puts
```

where none of the symbols have been assigned addresses yet. This is all good.

Then, I linked it using the following:
`$ gcc -Wall test.o –o test`

Then checked the symbols like below:
`$ nm test`

I got the following:

```
0000000100401080 T main
0000000100401000 T mainCRTStartup
0000000100401640 T malloc
0000000100403000 R msg
0000000100401650 T posix_memalign
00000001004010d0 T puts
```

while I was expecting the symbol `puts` being something like
U puts@@GLIBC_x.x.x`.

It seems like I did not have the shared libraries, or I'm not using the process correctly. What is wrong then? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using objdump

```
objdump -x test.exe 

        DLL Name: cygwin1.dll
        vma:  Hint/Ord Member-Name Bound-To
        813c       15  __cxa_atexit
        814c       46  __main
        8158      108  _dll_crt0
        8164      115  _impure_ptr
        8174      257  calloc
        8180      373  cygwin_detach_dll
        8194      375  cygwin_internal
        81a8      403  dll_dllcrt0
        81b8      579  free
        81c0      909  malloc
        81cc     1015  posix_memalign
        81e0     1170  puts
        81e8     1196  realloc
```

so `puts` is an external symbol taken from `cygwin1.dll` shared lib

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a good point - it shows that the symbol puts is linked to cygwin1.dll. Very interesting. I have a gcc compiler which is supposed to have its standard libraries. I would think when the gcc compiler is invoked it should try to use its own libraries, instead of cygwin. Any explanation for my follow-up. Thank you so much. I'm learning.

Comment: cygwin1.dll includes inside the standard C library for Cygwin.

Comment: What flags should I use when compiling so that it would only use the libraries from gcc itself? I have downloaded the gcc source repository and compiled it locally. I would like to use all gcc and use cygwin as just the OS. Thanks for your answer and knowledge.

Comment: The cygwin DLL embeds its own libc for use by cygwin itself.  You can't use a different libc side-by-side with it unless you prefix the symbols with something to differentiate them from the libc in cygwin.